# how can i create an array two arrays, one from 0 to 100 and one that is the running sum of the first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my current javascript wit d 0 to 100 array but I need to do the running sum right beside it?

```js
function goNow()
{ var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var text = "";
 var faruk = new Array(100);
 for(var i=0;i<faruk.length;i=i + 1)
 {
  text  += i + "</br>";

 }
 output.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
}<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ltp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="goNow()">ClickMe</button>
<div id="output">Change Me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need an array for this? Are you planning to store the values into arrays instead of the DOM? Currently `faruk` is practically useless.

Comment: Probably a homework assignment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function goNow()
{ var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var text = "";
  var sum=0;
 var faruk = new Array(100);
 for(var i=0;i<faruk.length;i=i + 1)
 {
sum += i;
  text  += i + "\t\t\t\t" + sum+"</br>";

 }
 output.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
}<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ltp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="goNow()">ClickMe</button>
<div id="output">Change Me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new var called `sum` and add it to the string where you need to print it.

```js
function goNow()
{ var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var text = "";
 var faruk = new Array(100);
 var sum = 0;
 for(var i=0;i<faruk.length;i=i + 1)
 {
   sum += i;
  text  += i + " Total sum so far:" + sum + "</br>";

 }
 output.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
}<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ltp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="goNow()">ClickMe</button>
<div id="output">Change Me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For having two arrays (as you asked), update in your function as below:

```
 var faruk = new Array(100);
 var rsum = new Array(100);
 for(var i=0;i<faruk.length;i=i + 1)
 {

  text  += i + "</br>";
  if (i==0)
     rsum[i] = 0;
  else 
     rsum[i] = rsum[i-1] + i;

 }
```

For same output without array, Andre Canilho & Kris Roofe answers are good enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
function goNow() {
  var inputArray = new Array(100);
  var outputArray = new Array(100);
  var sum = 0;
  for (var idx = 1; idx <= 100; idx++) {
    sum = sum + idx
    inputArray[idx] = idx + " - " + sum;
  }
  var outputString = "";
  inputArray.forEach(function(value) {
    outputString += value + "<br />";
  });
  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = outputString;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goNow()">Print</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also do as follows;

```js
var goNow = _ => output.innerHTML = new Array(100).fill()
                                                  .reduce((p,_,i) => i ? [p[0] += "<br>" + i + ":" + (p[1]+i), p[1]+i]
                                                                       : p, ["0:0",0])[0];
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ltp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="goNow()">ClickMe</button>
<div id="output">Change Me</div>
</body>
</html>
```